# Best Practice? Restart Centos service via ssh securely?

Tags: security, service, centos

I have a need to restart a CentOS service remotely via ssh during an automated, unattended process (executing a build on some software from a build server), but am unsure how to best implement security.  Help is needed! ;-)

Environment:

Running an ssh login on a remote box, I want to execute on my server something like:

```
/sbin/service jetty restart.
```

The ssh call is being made during a maven build process (probably doesn't affect anything, really).

I want the ssh session to login with a user that has practically zero permissions on the server except to execute the above.

I can set up shared key access for the ssh session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea to use an ssh key. You can then use a 'forced command' for that particular key, so it won't be able to run any other commands. See http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to forced command--very cool.  I combined that with the following entry in /etc/sudoers:  `jetty ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/jetty`.  The forced command i'll set up will be something like: `command="/etc/init.d/jetty stop;/etc/init.d/jetty start" [begin pub key string.]`